# SQLite/MySQL replace only if timestamp of row is newer

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm working on a sync engine and am stuck on a problem:

I need to **bulk INSERT OR REPLACE** multiple items in one query **but only if the timestamp 'lastModified' of the item is newer** than it's current value in the database (if the item exists - if the item doesn't exist yet in the db, then it just should be inserted).

What I've come up with so far is this:

```
REPLACE INTO tableName (id, name, lastModified) VALUES
CASE WHEN lastModified < [itemLastModified] THEN ([itemId], [itemName], [itemLastModified]), END
CASE WHEN lastModified < [itemLastModified] THEN ([itemId], [itemName], [itemLastModified]), END
CASE WHEN lastModified < [itemLastModified] THEN ([itemId], [itemName], [itemLastModified]) END
```

but that won't work obviously, since each case statement searches all rows in the table and not concentrates on the current item. Further more nothing would happen if the item didn't exists yet, I guess...

Does anyone know a good way to solve that problem?

Comment: Add a where clause including a null value to ensure inserts happen when the row doesn't exist

Comment: Well I guess that won't solve the problem to only update if the current column lastModified is older than the value of the updating item...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the new data into a temporary table. Then do:

```
REPLACE INTO tableName (id, name, lastModified)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.lastModified
FROM tempTable t1
LEFT JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.lastModified > t2.lastModified
```

The `SELECT` query will return all rows in the temporary table that have a newer modification time or there's no matching row in the original table.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Barmar, I'll try that approach... I'd have to drop the table immediately after right? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about SQLite, but MySQL temporary tables are dropped automatically when you close the connection.